# Efficient way to merge key value lists from character arrays

Tags: string, algorithm, delphi, optimization, sorting

At the core of one of our applications we have to merge key value lists. Because this merge function is called all the time, it has to be as fast as possible. Trading off memory for extra speed is acceptable.

Our application is written in Delphi, so I will be referencing some Delphi specific routines, but I suppose this problem might be of interest independent of the language used to solve it.

### Requirements

- The two input key value lists ("original" and "update") are passed in as pointers to character arrays, e.g. `'Key1=Value1'#13#10'Key2=Value2'#10'Key3=Value3'#13#10#10'Key4=Value4'`. Note that key and value are separated by '=' and key value pairs may be separated by any combination of the characters `#13` and `#10`.
- In the output key value pairs will always be separated by `#13#10`.
- The order of key value pairs in the output does not matter.
- If one of the inputs contains a duplicate key, it is OK to keep the duplicate. However, retaining only one key is also acceptable, since duplicates should not be in there in the first place. If the original and the update contain the same key, the value from the update is to be kept.
- I am dealing with ASCII characters only.

### My Solution

At the heart of my solution is a dictionary that maps a key (string) to a pointer to and the length of the memory block containing the value. This map is sorted on the keys. It can be reset before use and shared across multiple calls of the merge routine, so we save on memory allocations and deallocations for the map and its entries.
Do the following for every input key value list:

- Iterate over every character in the input.
- When encountering a key value separator, extract the key and scan ahead to the end of the value.
- If the key exists in the map, update the value pointer and length we determined by scanning ahead.
- Skip over all `#13` and `#10` characters after the value to get to the beginning of the next key.
- Repeat until the end of the input.

With the map filled, build the output string by iterating over the map, concating the key, a key value separator, a copy of the value based on the given position and length, and "\r\n" for every entry. Don't forget the final null-terminator.

### Ideas for optimizations

I have tried the following things, measuring performance using the QueryPerformanceCounter Windows API function.

- I originally thought keeping the map sorted was too much work when the number of keys was small. However, as it turns out even with only two or three keys, keeping the map sorted resulted in pretty much the same performance.
- The map contains the key as a string, meaning I have to extract the key from the character array and a create a string from it using Delphi's SetString routine. The way I understand [Delphi strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types), this has to involve a memory copy, which I would like to avoid. However, storing just a pointer and a length for the key and then comparing them using the [CompareString routine from the Windows unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317759%28VS.85%29.aspx) was much slower than extracting keys as strings and comparing them using CompareStr from SysUtils. I assume this is because the CompareString implementation is slower. Is there maybe a different routine for comparing strings that accepts pointers and a length as its inputs? I haven't found one, though.
- To keep the map sorted, I am using the sorting algorithm from Classes.TStringList which is a quick sort, if I'm not mistaken. Is there maybe a different sorting algorithm better suited for this scenario?

What other optimizations or even entirely different algorithms could you think of?

Comment: You can write #0 to source array after each key and value. This will allow you to use any functions which accept PChar's  as parameters.

Comment: If both sources contain the same key, is it ok to keep the duplicats, too ?

Comment: How big are the typical value lists? The question of what is the optimum solution depends on it.

Comment: @wildplasser if both sources contained the same key, I would want to keep the value from the second one, only. That is the point of the merge.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin I think approx. 20 key value pairs is the most common size of the two lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can tell, your solution is good and will be hard to improve upon.

The only suggestion I would make would be to use hashing for the dictionary rather than a sorted list of keys and binary search. You could use Delphi's `TDictionary<TKey,TValue>` assuming its performance was reasonable. For `TKey` you would use a custom record implementing your map (position and length). Similarly for `TValue`. You would have to implement your own comparer which could be done easily enough without incurring heap allocations.

Having said all of this, are you 100% sure that heap allocations are as evil as you think they are for this application? You should try a naive implementation using `TDictionary<string,string>` and profile the app to prove that it is spending significant time in the dictionary code. Another benefit of such an approach would be that, if indeed heap allocation was a problem, you could use the `string` based version as a reference implementation for testing purposes. Your pointer offset+length based version is sure to be a bug factory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with Delphi 2006, so I can't use generics. I could, of course, code up such a dictionary myself...

Comment: All the same, the most important advice I have offered is to profile to be sure that this optimisation is essential.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "This map is sorted on the keys" and phrase "keeping the map sorted" and stuff re pointers and lengths makes it sound like you sort an array of pointers after each insertion into the array.  If that is so, you might find that [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) runs faster than Quicksort.

Maintaining a balanced search tree probably would be a better approach.  An [AA tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree) is easy to code and has performance similar to that of a red-black tree, *i.e.,* O(ln n) inserts, lookups, and deletes.  If you really are sorting an array after each insertion, using a search tree would reduce insert time from O(n ln n) to O(ln n).

To read the keys out in order, use [in-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inorder) which runs in worst-case time O(n ln n).

*Updated: corrected pre-order to in-order*

Comment: I like the tree-approach, though I am not sure whether the overhead of memory (de)allocations when adding (removing) elements will eat up any speed gains. As of now, I have an array to store my pointers that can be re-used for each operation. I will have to profile the two solutions and get back to you.